# How to get viewport fullwidth images in Bootstrap 3

Tags: css, breakout

I'm trying to achieve images that breakout past their parent container to occupy 100% of the x-axis in the viewport, but no matter if I try

```
img-fluid
```

or this via CSS

```
.breakout { 
position: relative;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, 0);
width: 100vw; 
}
```

it doesn't work.

[Here is my example post](https://middll.github.io/2017/03/31/Testing-middll/)

And [here](https://github.com/middll/middll.github.io) is my repository for viewing my code.  Please note, I've basically returned it to 'vanilla' status and am still a novice with front-end.  The theme is based on Start Bootstrap's 'Clean Blog'.

Comment: Please contain your answer to StackOverflow without having to use links to external demos. This way any answer to your question can be used by others without having to follow links that die/change.

Comment: My apologies.  How do I illustrate the finished webpage inside StackOverflow when asking questions?

Also, is it okay to link to GitHub repositories?

Comment: You should, in this case, try to break out the HTML CSS which affects your site. Maybe in an external jsfiddle(http://jsfiddle.net/) or in a runnable code demo in your question.